# startActivityForResult From Fragment Not Working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have been fighting with this problem for hours now and have looked at pretty much every other post about this issue but can't find where I am going wrong.  Please let me know if I am missing something simple.

Activity 1 ( hosts a CreateFragment)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ((CreateFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CreateFragment.TAG)).resultReturned(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

CreateFragment:

```
private void chooseContact() {
    Intent chooseContactInappIntent = new Intent( getActivity(), ContactPickerActivity.class );
    getActivity().startActivityForResult( chooseContactInappIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST );
}

 public void resultReturned( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
    switch ( requestCode ) {
        case PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST:
            if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
               //Do Cool Things
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

ContactPickerActivity:

```
@Override
public void onContactSelected( Object data) {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("data",data);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Activity One hosts a CreateFragment, when the use clicks a button in the CreateFragment the fragment calls the chooseContact() method which starts a new ActivityForResult.  The ContactPickerActivity then displays the user a list of contacts.  When the user selects a contact the onContactSelected method is called creating a new intent to pass back the selected data and then calls finish.  I thought this would either call the onActivityResult in the base activity or the CreateFragment, but neither are called.

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment class work fine if you call at MainActivity onActivityResult override method and you don't need to changes inside the fragment class.
So
In Fragment that calls startActivityForResult like this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST || requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)) {

          // its not complicated .....    
        }
}
```

In MainActivity Class are must to call onActivityResult Also.

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }
```